# TDD. Please, help me solve the error

Tags: ruby, tdd

TDD:

```
describe RPNCalculator do

  attr_accessor :calculator

  before do
    @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
  end

it "adds two numbers" do
  calculator.push(2)
  calculator.push(3)
  calculator.plus
  calculator.value.should == 5
end
end
```

my code :

```
class RPNCalculator
attr_accessor :calculator

def initialize()
  @calculator = []
end

def RPNCalculator(x=0,y=0)
@calculator.push(x)
@calculator.push(y)
@calculator.map {|x,y| x + y }
end
```

error:

```
RPNCalculator
adds two numbers (FAILED - 1)
```

Failures:

```
1)RPNCalculator adds two numbers
Failure/Error: calculator.push(2)
NoMethodError:
undefined method `push' for #<RPNCalculator:0x000000021b85a8 @calculator=[]>
```

Comment: how you created object `calculator`?

Comment: I don't create object. Just run script with Rake command from terminal.

Comment: You should probably avoid having a variable `@calculator` in your solution. It is not in any way linked to the variable in the test name. To solve the test, you must create a class called `RPNCalculator` (which you have done), and it must provide methods `initialize` (which is called via `new`), `push`, `plus` and `value` - those are what the test calls. The internal variables in your class don't matter to the test (so, actually it *is ok* to call it "calculator", but you just might confuse yourself )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your test where you call `calculator.push(2)`. You are calling that on the object `RPNCalculator` which does not have a method called `push`. It is rather the instance variable `@calculator` within the class, which you instantiated to an `Array`, which has that method.

Your test should actually be:

```
it "adds two numbers" do
  @calculator.RPNCalculator(2,3).value.should == 5
end
```

I should point out that it is considered bad form to have a method name that starts with a capital letter.

If I may be so bold as to guess what your test is trying to get at, you are wanting to `push` numbers into your `RPNCalculator` and continue to push numbers and get the sum of those numbers at will. If this is indeed the case, you may be looking for something like this:

```
class RPNCalculator
attr_accessor :calculator

def initialize()
  @calculator = []
end

def push(*num)
  # Use is_a? in order to ensure anything added to
  # the Array can later be added together 
  @calculator.push(*num) if num.all? {|n| n.is_a? Numeric}
  # If you would like this to work with any class that can be added
  # then change 'n.is_a? Numeric' to 'n.respond_to? :+'
end

def plus
  @calculator.reduce(:+)
end

def value
  plus
end
```

Doing that should make your original test work with no alteration.

Example of usage:

```
calc = RPNCalculator.new
calc.push(3)
calc.push(2)
calc.plus #=> 5
calc.push(6)
calc.plus #=> 8   
calc.push(1,2,3,4)
calc.plus #=> 18
```

Notice I use the splat operator (the asterisk) in the method definition. I would suggest doing some [reading](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) on the topic. It is worth learning and loving.

Comment: Hello. I will rename method, thank's. I can't change the test.

Comment: @JohnOggy I went beyond explaining what is wrong and why you are getting that error to adding some suggestions as to how you might design your class to make the tests pass. You will eventually want to refactor the class with more functionality beyond what I'm suggesting here but that's what TDD is about, right?

Comment: how add more than two elements?

Comment: @JohnOggy I updated my answer to include how you might add more elements.

Comment: I trying to do this test
https://github.com/JohnOggy/test/blob/master/12_rpn_calculator/rpn_calculator_spec.rb

Comment: Looks like a fun test. You should be able to learn a good deal by getting the rest of the specs to pass. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class RPNCalculator
attr_accessor :calculator

def initialize()
  @calculator = []
end

def RPNCalculator(x=0,y=0)
  @calculator.push(x)
  @calculator.push(y)
  p @calculator.reduce(&:+)
end
end

cal = RPNCalculator.new
cal.RPNCalculator(10,20) #30
```